# I have 10-15 buttons on page.I want to move 1 button left-right using iquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have more then 10-15 button on page ,i want to move only 1 button left-right using jquery but right all button starts moving left-right.Even every button have different class name.
Please tell me the solution.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        sayNoVisual(100, 1);
    });

    function sayNoVisual(px, r) {
        $('.stepback').animate({
            'marginLeft': px
        }, function() {
            $('.stepback').animate({
                'marginLeft': 1
            }, function() {
                if (r-- > 0) {
                    sayNoVisual(px, r);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

And here are the buttons:

```
 <button type="submit" class="stepback" data-ruleindex="1" > <img alt="Step back" src="46887_106291039431913_6252895_n.jpg" title="step back one cycle" width="60" height="60"></button> 
 <button type="submit" class="stepfwd" data-ruleindex="1"> <img alt="Step forward" src="467_n.jpg" title="step forward one cycle" width="60" height="60"></button>
```

In code i used only 1st button class but both button are moving from left to right.

css class used is:

```
<style type="text/css">
            .stepback, .play, .pause, .stepfwd, .tostart, .toflagback, .toflagfwd, .toend {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:0;
                outline:0;
                font-size:100%;
                vertical-align:baseline;
                background:transparent
            }

            .stepback:active, .play:active, .pause:active, .stepfwd:active, .tostart:active,      .toflagback:active, .toflagfwd:active, .toend:active {
                position:relative;
                top:3px;
            }

            .stepback:hover, .play:hover, .pause:hover, .stepfwd:hover, .tostart:hover,     .toflagback:hover, .toflagfwd:hover, .toend:hover {
                position:relative;
                top:3px;
            }
        </style>
```

Comment: Why ask twice? Duplicate...

Comment: @Jonathan single button should move but here all  buttons are moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <button type="submit" class="stepfwd" data-ruleindex="1"> <img alt="Step forward" src="467_n.jpg" title="step forward one cycle" width="60" height="60"></button> 
<button type="submit" class="stepback" data-ruleindex="1" > <img alt="Step back" src="46887_106291039431913_6252895_n.jpg" title="step back one cycle" width="60" height="60"></button>
```

see [Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4XZL/)  - Just switched which one was on the left

technically only the left button is moving, but where do you expect the right one to go?? It has no choice unless you change the positioning the something else like absolute

Example of that [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4XZL/3/)

```
.stepback{position:absolute;}
.stepfwd{position:absolute;left:100px;}
```